# Question related to IntegerPart

Tags: numerics, built-in-symbols, numerical-value

I am having trouble understanding the following result:

```
Through[{IntegerPart,FractionalPart}[{100 4.02}]]
```

> ```
> {{401}, {1.}}
> ```

Shouldn't it read `{{402}, {0.}}`?

I understand that in the [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPart.html) one reads

> "`IntegerPart[x]+FractionalPart[x]` is always exactly `x`. "

which **is** actually the case here, but one also reads:

> "`IntegerPart[x]` *in effect* takes all digits to the left of the decimal point and drops the others. "

(emphasis added) which **isn't** the case here.

I was using `IntegerPart[100#[[1]]]&` as a second argument in `GatherBy` over a long list of entries where the first entry was a real number like `4.02` above.

It is actually the case that modifying the example produces the following

```
Through[{IntegerPart,FractionalPart}[{100 4.021}]]
```

> ```
> {{402}, {0.1}}
> ```

Is this bug material or should this behavior be expected?

Comment: Have look at `FullForm[100 4.02]` and `FullForm[Through[{IntegerPart, FractionalPart}[{100 4.02}]]]`. The number `0.02` cannot be represented exactly in machine precision.

Comment: thanks for the hint! got it!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: However, `Through[{IntegerPart, FractionalPart}[{Rationalize@(100 4.02)}]]` returns what you are expecting. I assume that `Rationalize` converts `0.02` to the rational number that when multiplied by 100 is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

As was kindly suggested by *@Henrik Schumacher*, `100 4.02` is **not** the same thing as `402`, which is what I was assuming `IntegerPart` was seeing as input.

Taking `FullForm[100 4.02]` reveals that the input to `IntegerPart` evaluates to `401.99999999999994'`, which in turn-as should be expected-evaluates to `{{401}, {1.}}` by `Through[{IntegerPart,FractionalPart}[{100 4.02}]]`.

So, the answer is, *"no, the result is **not** a bug; instead `IntegerPart` operates exactly as it is expected to in the documentation. What appears as a discrepancy is due to the **failure** to realize how **not** all numbers can be represented exactly."*